# How to get Intent from Google analytics BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, google-analytics

We want to use  Google analytics to implement referrer tracking, by following the documentention:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/campaigns , and I can see the referrer in the logcat like this:
**"Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Campaign found: utm_source=testSource"**

But,How to save the reference to a string like this **"String str1 = Intent.getStringExtra("referrer")"** from Google analytics BroadcastReceiver?

Appreciate any comments, suggestions